# SQL server 2016 (13.0.5026.0) Standard. High CPU ussage even without user queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, wait-types

So SQL server CPU ussage is around 20% even when no users are making queries

[image: SQL CPU]

I query the sysprocesses, and i can see some internal spid's:

```
select * from master.dbo.sysprocesses order by cpu desc
```

[image: high CPU ussage process]

Any idea of what is this `RESOURCE MONITOR` with `PREEMPTIVE_XE_CALLBACKEXECUTE` wait type, and why does it take so much CPU; read somewhere it can be some memory management process, but in our case we have a fixed memory reserved for SQL Server:

[image: Memory settings]

Comment: what are system specs ? how many cores, memory etc ? is it physical box, or vm ? is VM sharing resources with other VMs on a host ?

Comment: What Extended Events sessions are running? Does the symptom disappear if you disable them?

Comment: 24GB memory, 4 cores 2,4Ghz. It's a VM, but not sharing memory; it has a fixed amount of memory assigned.

Comment: For the moment we restarted the server, and the issue is gone. Our ERP system has some Ex. events, will try to stop them if it happens again. I've also reduced the minimum memory amount to 12GB; I hope this way, the memory liberation will happen more often

Comment: Are any of the databases participating in an Availability Group? I ask because it looks like one CPU core is tied up (24% usage on a 4-core system), and there was a bug fixed in SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU13 related to [AG health checks getting caught in an infinite loop burning up 1 core](https://www.joshthecoder.com/2020/06/22/a-bug-with-ag-health-checks.html) (disclosure: that's my blog),  which could only be resolved by a reboot.